# Suggestions for wiki farm with good latex support

Tags: latex, soft-question

I've decided to start a wiki to do collaborative mathematics. However I don't have access or control over a server. So I need a wiki farm. I've tried out pbworks and wikidot, but their latex support is not as straightfoward as say wordpress.

Do you have a suggestion of which wiki farm to use?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what is a wiki _farm_?

Comment: Kind of like a wiki hatchery, but on land. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for a wiki that can handle LaTeX-style equations, then you should take a look at instiki.  Not only does it display mathematics properly, it can also export pages to LaTeX.

http://www.instiki.org/show/HomePage

Answer (score 5):

You have [Wikia](http://www.wikia.com/Wikia) which uses the same software as Wikipedia. It's a complete and total latex support (i.e. I doubt you can add and install new packages) but you have a pretty good support for formulae, just like in Wikipedia.

I think that if you want something that has complete latex support (i.e. you can upload and compile .tex source files) you'd have to hack something of your own.

For further comparison: [Comparison of wiki farms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_wiki_farms)

Comment: As a long-term Wikipedia editor, I must say that LaTeX support in MediaWiki sucks.

Answer (score 2):

I was investigating the same question recently myself. This is what I came up with.

The best support for TeX input to my knowledge has Noösphere which is the engine behind PlanetMath

http://planetmath.org/

I however do not believe that you can install Noösphere on your own-servers because it is proprietary application. Please somebody correct me if I am wrong.

On the another hand I really like PmWiki

http://www.pmwiki.org/

which also has support for TeX input.

http://www.pmwiki.org/wiki/Cookbook/TrueLatex

There is another feature of PmWiki that I really like. You can store your date in plain text files. Most but not all Wikis do require some kind of database.

Comment: I am not resurrecting old thread. I just changed the recommendation for PmWiki add-on for TeX support based on my own experience in the past couple of months. I am using PmWiki on several sites and it is an outstanding peace of software! 